# How to read time of flight for Emirates airline?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bookings, solo-travel, emirates

First of all, I'm a solo traveller and this is my first time. I decided to book a flight online (eticket) with Emirates.com. I'm confused on how to read the time of the flight so for example:

[image]

The time as shown for this flight (BAH to AKL) is **3:45** and the time appears to be in 24-hour format. Now, Does 3:45 here mean (the local time for BAH airport) which is **3:45 AM** in 12-hour format?

What about arriving time in which time zone will it be?

I tried to look for an answer in emirates.com. Still nervous and confused, but I'm trying my best not to get lost.

Comment: yes, it's ALWAYS THE LOCAL TIME at each end.

Comment: Thanks, as a side point, I'm wondering if I'll be able to catch the connecting flight because the connection is 4 hours only?

Comment: Should be no problem to make the connection, 4 hours should be plenty. And even if it wasn't, looks like you're booking it as a single ticket - which means that if you miss the connection because of delays, the airline will rebook you on the next flight.

Comment: @EMotion Yes, I'm booking the ticket as a single ticket.

Comment: Most airline booking sites will give a warning if the connection time is too short. This can vary by airline and airport, but is usually somewhere around 45 minutes. 4 hours is *plenty*. You'll have time to visit some shops, get some food, possibly even take a nap.

Comment: 4 hours _only_?  what do you plan on doing during the connection?

Comment: I've travelled a few times on Emirates to NZ via Dubai from the UK. The Dubai connection time is generally 2-3 hours and even that feels long; 4 hours is nothing to worry about (especially as that first flight is so short anyway). Missing a connecting flight is generally only an issue if they're two different *airline groups* (a so-called "hacker fare"). Have an amazing trip! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Times for flights are almost always given as local time in a 24 hour format.

The departure time is given in the timezone of the departing airport and the arrival time is specified in the timezone of the arrival airport.

---

In your example, the first flight is departing at 03:45 hours in the morning Bahrain time (GMT+3), from Bahrain. It arrives at Dubai (DXB) at 06:00 hours, Dubai time (GMT+4). The next flight departs from Dubai at 10:05 that morning, GMT+4. It arrives in Auckland at 11:10 in the morning on the following day, GMT+13.

---

The main exception to this is flights departing inside the United States, where times are given in a twelve hour format, with either an "a" to indicate before noon (a from ***a***nte meridiem) or a "p" to indicate the afteroon (***p***ost meridiem). If there is no letter then it is probably a 24 hour time, what the Americans sometimes call "military time".

Comment: ... and 12-hour times are almost never written with a leading zero for the hours, so 03:45 is clearly in 24-hour format.

Comment: It is not so much that flights departing inside the USA use the 12 hour formats, it is more that US based airlines use the 12 hour format.

Comment: And that the US population in general uses 12-hour format, to such extent that 24-hour time is commonly called military time here, as that's the only place a lot of the public hears it being used. I have several friends who have no idea how to read 24-hour time.